# Cookie not set in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a authorize filter

```
public class LandedAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
   protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {
      if (httpContext == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("httpContext");
      if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["LegalDisclaimer"].Value != "Accepted")
      {
         return false;
      }
      return true;
}
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext){
   string url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(url);
   filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
   new RouteValueDictionary {
     { "action", "Index" },
     { "controller", "Landing" },
     { "returnUrl", url }
   });
}
```

}

and my Landing Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.rdParm = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult Accept(string returnUrl)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("LegalDisclaimer", "Accepted");
            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```

Then I set up a controller like

```
[Landed] 
public class someController : Controller
{
contoller actions here
}
```

The problem is the LegalDisclaimer cookie is never set and always returning null. This is my first attempt at learning Authorize filter in mvc and its 3 days without any progress. Can anyone help me debug this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ignore this - see the update below**

It looks like you are never able to set the cookie. The Accept action in your `LandingController` is, I assume, the only thing that sets the cookie. However you can never get there because the custom Authorize filter (`LandedAttribute`) that you've created stops the application from getting there (because the cookie is not set).

You probably want to add an `[AllowAnonymous]` on that action to allow it through so that the cookie can be set.

e.g.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Accept()
{
    // body of the action here.
}
```

**UPDATE**

I just realised your `LandedAttribute` is attempting to read the outgoing cookies, not the incoming cookies.

You have `HttpContext.Current.Response`. Use the cookies on the `Request`, not the `Response`

Your Controller action should still use the Response, because you are setting the outgoing cookie there.

Comment: Its getting to the accept attribute. But I tried your answer and it is still keeps on getting me on the Disclaimer Page

Comment: "Accept attribute"???? You have a LandedAttribute, or an Accept controller action. I'm not sure which you mean.

Comment: I meant action not attribute

Comment: Mr Mackay mmmkay you sir are my hero +1